# R knit - knit a section of a document

Tags: r, knitr

I am working on a large knitr document that takes some time to calculate the initial results. Is there a way to knit a subsection of the document, ie. after the longer calculations have taken place for the purpose of development? I would prefer not to have to pre-calculate the results, save them and then read them into the document in order to expedite developing the final plots and tables.

Thanks,
 John

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't leveraging the caching features of knitr?  (https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider breaking your document up into smaller ['child' documents](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/).  Then you can process just the child you are interested in.  As I mentioned in the comments, alternatively, you might consider using the caching features of knitr.

Comment: Thanks rpierce - I have not employed caching in the past but after reading the knitr docs further it does seem to fit my needs exactly.